# Traefik 2 Dashboard Custom Context Path

Tags: docker, traefik

I would like to change the context path for the Traefik dashboard from e.g. `https://apps.example.com/` to `https://apps.example.com/traefik`, as I have Heimdall routed to `https://apps.example.com/`.  All the examples I could find are for Traefik 1.x.  What would be the easiest way to do this?  My current config (which doesn't work):

**traefik.toml:**

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint]
      to = "websecure"
      scheme = "https"

  [entryPoints.websecure]
    address = ":443"

[api]
  dashboard = true
  insecure = true

[log]
  level = "DEBUG"

[certificatesResolvers.cloudflare.acme]
  email = "email@email.com"
  storage = "acme.json"
  [certificatesResolvers.cloudflare.acme.dnsChallenge]
    provider = "cloudflare"
    resolvers = ["1.1.1.1:53", "8.8.8.8:53"]

[providers.docker]
  watch = true
  network = "web"
  exposedByDefault = false
  endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"

[providers.file]
  filename = "traefik_dynamic.toml"
```

**traefik_dynami.toml:**

```
[http.routers.api]
  rule = "Host(`apps.example.com`) && Path(`/traefik`)"
  entrypoints = ["websecure"]
  service = "api@internal"
  [http.routers.api.tls]
    certResolver = "cloudflare"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement as well. I followed the suggestion [here](https://github.com/traefik/traefik/issues/5853#issuecomment-663914401) on a feature request to be able to set the context path.

I also saw others [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59577106/67796) suggesting it possible using the configuration file.